# CS1961: Invalid variance. Parameter must be invariantly valid

Tags: c#

I tried to create the following class

```
public interface IOptionsAsync<[DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicParameterlessConstructor)] out TOptions>
    where TOptions : class
{
    Task<TOptions> GetAsync();
}
```

But, `Task<TOptions> GetAsync();` line is giving an error that I don't understand. The error reads

> CS1961: Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TOptions' must be invariantly valid on 'IOptionsAsync.GetAsync()'. TOptions is covariant.

What does this error mean? How can I fix it?
[image]